# Magnetic stripe credit card

Tags: credit-card, fraud, magnetic-stripe-card

Do ATM in London accept magnetic stripe? If yes can a thief still duplicate a credit card and use it in an ATM which accepts magnetic stripes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do so. A crook can use a cloned magnet stripe card on an ATM in London, which accept magnet stripe cards.